# Why does my rendered image not have the resolution I set in the 'Dimensions' panel?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, image, resolution

I have set the resolution in Blender to 11811 x 5906 and 100%. This you can see here:

[image: blender resolution]

After I press <kbd>F12</kbd> it starts to render. When it's finished I go *Image> Save* and save the image at a special directory. When I click back in windows at the image and go to Characteristics> Details I see this:

[image: windows image details]

As you can see the image is not 11811 x 5906 as set in Blender. It is 2896 x 1448.

Comment: What image format did you use to save the render?

Comment: @rjg I save it as PNG

Comment: I can render and save the image just fine as PNG with the Blender 2.8 release with both Eevee and Cycles. Can you open the saved image in Blender and check if the resolution is actually wrong? Seems like Windows properties already misreports the bit depth, because PNG can't save 32-bit per channel, it's either 8-bit or 16-bit so perhaps the resolution that is shown is inaccurate as well.

Comment: @rjg When I open up the Image in the Rendering tab of blender and go to Image it says the exact numbers windows says too.

Comment: Do you use *Render Region* and *Crop to Render Region*?

Comment: @rjg Only `Crop to Render Region`. I do not use `Render Region`. I didn't change it. It was a setting by default.